# Why do my commands not work in command blocks when they work correctly in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make a system in which gives a player Slow Falling "indefinitely" when in a certain area/height (specially, in a specified rectangular are and from Y171 to Y189), then replacing it with the same except of 10 seconds instead when within a certain height lower than that (Y133 to Y171).

To do this, I've created a command system that does the following;

1. (Chain 1) Looks for a player in the jumping area who doesn't have the tag `effect`. (the reason why I wanted Slow Falling). Then, gives them that tag.
2. (C1) Looks for those who have the tag, and applies the indefinite Slow Falling.
3. (C2) Looks for those both not between Y171 and Y189 and not in the boxed area, and removes the `effect` tag.
4. (C2) Clears the Slow Falling effect for those without the `effect` tag.

Chain 3 is the problematic one. What it should do is the following;

1. Searches for those without the `effect` tag between Y133 and Y171, and adds the tag `in`.

   ```
   execute as @a[tag=!effect,y=133,dy=38] at @s run tag @s add in
   ```
2. Gives those with tag `in` Slow Falling for 10 seconds

   ```
   execute as @a[tag=in] at @s run effect give @s minecraft:slow_falling 10 1
   ```
3. Removes tag `in`

   ```
   execute as @a[tag=in] at @s run tag @s remove in
   ```

The commands work perfectly fine on their own in chat, sent one-by-one. Attempting to put them in a command chain causes them to do absolutely nothing. I've never seen this happen before, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Are you trying to have an infinitely large area on the X and Z axes, but only detect that certain Y-area?

Comment: correct, though "infinitely" isn't the right word since i'm limiting the space of my map via world border. if absolutely needed i *could* specify an X and Z area, but seeing as the other command with only Y specified (Y171 to Y189) works fine, i doubt that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your target selector `@a[tag=!effect,y=133,dy=38]`. When you specify `dy` without specifying `dx` or `dz`, they are automatically added and default to 0. This means that the game is testing for a one block wide and long area. So in reality, the game is actually testing for `@a[tag=!effect,y=133,dx=0,dy=38,dz=0]`

The only reason why your commands work in chat is because when you are typing them in chat, the position that the selector calculates from is set to your location, meaning it creates its detection box starting from your position, so your hitbox will always be touching it, so it always succeeds. When you put it in a command block, the detection box is created from the command block's position, and you won't always be in that area.

To fix this, you can use a predicate to detect entity position, this is not subject to the rule that you must have all three at once.

Comment: i don't think this is it. as i'd said earlier, a similar command works perfectly without issue, so if that were the case, then that command shouldn't work either.

Comment: @EarthToAccess Did you read my entire post for my reasoning? I don't understand why you don't believe me, and I am *positively certain* that my reasoning is correct. If you disagree with me, I'd be happy to explain this all to you in chat.

Comment: i did read it; and as i said, another command, in a command block, with only ``y=`` and ``dy=`` in it, works perfectly fine. if it were an issue with the lack of ``x``/``dx`` and ``z/dz``, that command block wouldn't fire either. i'm fine with moving this into chat if you need more info.

Comment: also, if that were the case, it to my knowledge shouldn't matter because ``at @s`` fires the command at the position of the executing entity as if they sent the command into chat.

Comment: @EarthToAccess I think we need to discuss this further. Let's go to the Minecraft Talk chat room

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm ExpertCoder14 is dead wrong. Whether you use x, z, dx, and dz or not, it's all the same. The repeating command block is unable to keep track of a plummeting character's y coordinate, but if you run the same exact command while falling there's zero problem.

Compare the two following pieces of code, which do the exact same thing, they fail in the repeat command block (which is confirmed to be on a loaded chunk and right next to a command block with the command /say hi to ensure they're both working) but the commands work perfectly in chat.

1. `/tp @a[y=50,dy=-50] 0 89 0`
2. `/tp @a[y=50,dy=-50,x=-1000,dx=2000,z=-1000,dz=2000] 0 89 0`

Have a look at another attribute that governs how far away the command block can affect things: Radius (or Distance, depending on version). If you're like me, then it's defaulting to too low a number. I'm in 1.12.2 right now, so we use r. When I slapped in a rm=0,r=9999, bam, it started working. Try throwing in distance=9999999 or whatever the equivalent for your version is.

You can also try doing an execute @a ~ ~ ~ in front of your commands (or, if you're in a higher version than 1.12.2, using execute at)